# How to populate WPF Label based on 2 or more WPF TextBoxes?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have 3 WPF TextBoxes that have segments of the URL.

I want to have those segments merged to see the full URL within a WPF Label.

How I can reach it by XAML?

Also I want to update this Label when user changes TextBoxes.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [MultiBinding with StringFormat](http://live.mscommunity.net/blogs/borissevo/archive/2009/01/20/wpf-trick-3-multibinding-and-stringformat.aspx).

You may also want to set UpdateSourceTrigger to PropertyChanged to for the member bindings. This will make sure the combined text gets updated as the user types the text and not only after he leaves the text box.

Comment: @Dmitry Those bindings can be any bindings you want, just specify ElementName to the text box and Text as Path.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is [multibinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx) with [StringFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat.aspx).

```
<TextBox Name="text1" />
<TextBox Name="text2" />
<TextBox Name="text3" />

<TextBox Name="Combined">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="[{0} - {1} - {2}]">
            <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="text1" />
            <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="text2" />
            <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="text3" />
         </MultiBinding>
     </TextBox.Text>
 </TextBox>
```